# A call to api inside an application and through external app returns different results

Tags: c#, wpf, webapi

I am connecting to an API and calling a method. However, one of the fields is behaving strangely.

For example, using Postman, I call the method in an API and get the result (this is the field that concerns me):

[image]

But then, using the same data, I will call the API from inside the application:

```
var swappingScreen = await client.GetReservationByNumberAsync(new GetReservationByNumberRequestDataRequestObject() { someParameters });
isSwap = swappingScreen.Reservation.IsScreenSwapped == 1;
```

And everytime the `isSwap` bool variable is false. Surely enough, when I set a breakpoint and see what's inside the resposne, I see this:

[image]

Things I checked:

1. The address of the API is correct (using the same one in Postman and in app)
2. The method is the same
3. The parameters are the same (in fact I copied the parameters directly from the request object)

The reference is added through WSDL file - i checked, the method is there, the field is there, it's correctly of `int` type.

Why could I be getting different responses here?

***CLARFICATION*** the value returned by the Postman is actually correct - the `0` when calling from app is not.

Comment: Do you have access to the API? If not, is there documentation on the API specifying reasons for this return value?

Comment: i recommend using network sniffer such as fiddler to see what exactly the api returns.
false might be the default for that Boolean maybe you have serialization problem

Comment: That's a common symptom of (de) serialiser failure. You likely have a problem in the proxy class. Could be as simple as adding an attribute to that property or change type.

Comment: post your model class